# What happens if my aws instance is located at the same site as another instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services

My apologies for being a super-newbie about this topic. I'm not even sure about the lingo to use, please do not cringe when you read this.

I currently have a daily upload process to a server located in a aws location. I do not own or control the aws server, it is a private 3rd party. I am uploading from a small town in Nevada. The aws server is located at us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com. My latency is bad and my ISP is simply not effective at maintaining the upload.

My ISP is not very good at delivering packets from my small town to the aws server. I get all kinds of error codes and have to resubmit. This is frustrating.

I had the thought: "Why don't I instance my own server at us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com?" that way when I perform the upload, both my instance and the 3rd party server will be in the same server room. Wouldn't that cut latency down to almost nothing? Wouldn't that make the data transfer essentially free? Wouldn't it bypass my ISP?

Can someone please let me know if this type of reasoning is correct? I'd like to know if it is a good idea or not, if aws permits such a thing, before I go through the effort.

Comment: Where is the source of the data that you're uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background**

"us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com" indicates that the server is behind a load balancer in the AWS US-East-1 region, in North Virginia. AWS currently has four regions in the USA, and many outside the USA, including California and Oregon in the West USA.

You could use either either the US East or West data centers. I would suggest you use the one closest to you.

Note that AWS is a complex enterprise environment. You will likely need advice from someone experienced to do this in a cost effective, secure way.

**Network**

If you put your own server into any AWS region then the connection between servers would be faster and more reliable as you expected.

If you have an unreliable internet connection then you may experience problems accessing the server in AWS. This could solve your backup problem, but could make the server unusable.

Fortunately it's relatively cheap to get a server in AWS to try this out yourself. You will probably want to retain someone with AWS expertise to help you with this.

**Cost**

It may not be cheaper, as data sent out of your server instance over the internet is charged at (currently) [$0.09 per GB](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/). If you set up a VPC peering connection this reduces to $0.01 / GB out and $0.01 /GB in. This is not affected by the region you choose.

**Migration**

There are multiple ways of getting either your server into AWS or moving your data up into a new server. You should talk to someone experienced with AWS about the options.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: You will still have to upload your data from your machine to your EC2 instance in US-East-1, so while the transfer from your box to their will be quick, you'll have all the same issues that you're currently having.

Now, if you download the data from another server, then you could simply download the data to your EC2 instance and then upload it to theirs, essentially cutting you out of the equation.